# ¿Cómo uso UrlFetchApp para comprobar conexión a Internet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

estoy haciendo un formulario con Google appScript para una encuesta, pero para evitar que algunas respuestas no se envíen (en caso de que la conexión a internet de la persona encuestada falle) estoy haciendo una comprobación mediante `UrlFetchApp` con el siguiente código del lado del servidor

```
function ChkConnection(){

  var content= UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google.com/", {method: "POST",
          muteHttpExceptions: true});
  var res = content.getResponseCode();
  return res;
 }
```

Pero si falla la conexión a internet (desactivo el wifi de mi laptop) me devuelve `Uncaught NetworkError: Se produjo un error en la conexión debido a HTTP 0` en la consola del navegador, alguna idea de como puedo devolver algún mensaje al cliente que diga que su internet falló ?

PD: Esta forma de hacerlo quizá no sea la más adecuada, pero aún soy nuevo programando, así que parece que es una manera más sencilla de entender, también intenté hacerlo con `navigator.onLine` pero leí que en algunas ocasiones no suele funcionar de manera correcta.
Saludos!

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas [`Navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) simplemente? Te devolverá `true` o `false` según haya conexión o no.

Comment: pensé utilizarlo pero incluso cuando no tienes acceso a internet te devuelve "true" si tienes una red local, investigué y te devuelve "false" solo cuando no estas en una red, por eso no me gustaría usarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comprobar si el usuario tiene acceso a Internet al hacer el envío de la respuesta no te sirve usar código del lado del servidor porque para llamar ese código debe tener conexión a Internet, en su lugar debes usar algo del lado del código del cliente.

Una de tantas opciones es usar

```javascript
google.script.run
  .withSuccssHandler(onSuccessHandler)
  .withFailureHandler(onFailureHandler)
  .doSomething(data);
```

`doSomething(data)` puede ser cualquier función del lado del servidor, incluso la función que uses para enviar los datos del formulario. Si bien puedes usar la función `ChkConnection` sería ineficiente porque de todas formas deberás llamar la función que recibirá los datos de tu formulario.

`onSuccessHandler` es un callback a ejecutarse en caso de que la función del lado del servidor se haya ejecutado de forma exitosa. Puedes usar esta función para mostrar un mensaje de confirmación de que los datos del formulario se enviaron correctamente.

`onFailureHandler` es un callback a ejecutarse en caso de que la función del lado del servidor haya devuelto un error. El error incluso puede ser que no se hayan enviado los datos del formulario debido a que falló la conexión de Internet.  Puedes usar esta función para mostrar un mensaje  de que los datos del formulario NO se enviaron y dar indicaciones sobre cómo proceder.

NOTA: Los nombres de las funciones/callback anteriores pueden ser cualquier nombre de función válido.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me ha venido de maravilla,